# The form can't be opened when I click the button

Tags: c#, visual-studio

When I try to click the button, Visual Studio said there is no errors and when I debug it, when I click it, it doesn't open the Settings form.
How to fix the bloat? Please help me.

```
private void BunifuImageButton5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            new Settings().Show();
        }
```

Comment: Please put a breakpoint on `new Settings().Show();`  and test **whether the breakpoint is being hit**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it possible that the BunifuImageButton5_Click method isn't connected as the BunifuImageButton5 event Click?

Try to check in the properties window of the BunifuImageButton5, in the section of events (the one with the lightning) and scroll down untill you find the click event and see if there is your method BunifuImageButton5_Click linked.

Another two things you can do are:

1)write two "Console.writeln("something");" before and after the instruction where you try to show the new form like

```
private void BunifuImageButton5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    Console.writeln("Before");
    new Settings().Show();
    Console.writeln("After");
}
```

and see if in the console you can see both the outputs.

2)Write a Console.writln("something"); inside the Settings constructor to see if the Form constructor is called:

```
public Settings() 
{
    InitializeComponents();
    Console.writeln("Initialized");
}
```

If you see the outputs of all of the cases, just add a Console.writeln("something"); on the "shown" event of the Settings form and see if the Show() method is being correctly called or there is some non-syntax error in your code.

To be more accurate you have to post the code of your forms and the structure of your project.

Comment: `Console.writeln`?